# How to catch when target is found using Vuforia for iOS?

Tags: vuforia

I need a simple way to detect when a target has been found or lost so that I can segue to a different Controller.

This question has been asked in several forums, but there was never a satisfactory answer. This particular post seems to be the most detailed, but it is over three years old.

https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/ios/trackableeventhandler-equivalent-ios

I can't find any documentation related to this on the Vuforia site.

Answer (score 0):

One of the methods that must be implemented by the VuforiaManagerDelegate is:

```
func vuforiaManager(_ manager: VuforiaManager!, didUpdateWith state: VuforiaState!)
```

When a target is found (an image is recognized by Vuforia) this property will change from 0 to 1 (or more, if multiple targets are identified):

```
numberOfTrackableResults
```

So it is simply a matter of checking if state.numberOfTrackableResults > 0 { your code here }

Answer (score 0):

on TrackableEventHandler script there is a function called OnTrackableStateChanged

you can sign up to this and do whatever you wanna do directly here or in OnTrackingFound();

`public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
                                        TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
                                        TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
        {
            if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
                newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
                newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
            {
                OnTrackingFound();
            }
            else
            {
                OnTrackingLost();
            }
        }`